# How should a frontend framework (like Vue/Angular) interact with a backend MVC framework (Laravel/Sails)

Tags: sails.js, vue.js

We need a restful backend that provides APIs for a mobile app.
We also need a admin website to manage the restful backend.

Right now we have Sails.js as the backend framework, Vue.js as the frontend framework.

I m pretty new to MVC frameworks and I am a little bit confused how should these two frameworks interact with each other:

Should:

- The frontend framework lives indepedently (maybe on a separate server), it calls api exposed by the backend framework, or
- The frontend framework lives INSIDE the Sails.js, acting as the "views" for the Sails framework

I am not even 100% sure is my question a valid question, I want to know which are the popular ways and is there any pros and cons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do both i.e. keep frontend framework in `Sails` project as well as separate independent project.

I have done both and I keep following points in mind while making this decision:

1. If the project is complex enough then its better to create a separate project using some scaffolding tool.
2. If the project is going to change frequently and evolve on its own then also its better to create a separate project.
3. If some one time/small view is to be made then I would prefer to keep it part of `Sails` project

Since you are using frontend framework for admin panel which I think
    will be complex, I would recommend you to create separate project on the same server.

You can use [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) for scaffolding. I have used it for some angular projects and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too wide for a single explanation, but the main concept is as per my understanding is *data binding*.

You can find a lot of [free screencasts](https://laracasts.com/series/learning-vue-step-by-step) for starting from scratch, assuming you already know some JavaScript.